# Unable to change birthdate on Facebook account

Tags: facebook

How can I change/correct my birthday on my Facebook profile after it was set incorrectly?

My roommate and a friend of hers went on my computer where my Facebook was open and changed my birthday. Apparently, when she decided to hit save, it asked if she was sure because it wouldn't be able to change back and she clicked "Yes" anyway.

The notice is:

> Note: you can only change your birthday a limited number of times.

Now I am unable to change my birthday back and am very upset about it.

Is there anything that can be done so that I can once again have my birthday on my profile and have it be correct?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has limits in a place around the number of times you can edit your birthday. If you recently edited your birthday, you may have to **wait a few days** before changing it again.

<sub>Resource: [Facebook Help](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=121641674584595)</sub>

Comment: Do you know what "a few days" actually translates to?

Comment: @ChrisF: I haven't experienced it but it should not take too long. Have you tried to change your birthday?

Comment: No. There was an answer from a low rep user asking the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to contact Facebook [through this form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=change_dob) and hopefully they should get back to you.